# Android SDK can't find folder tools

Tags: android, android-source

Through Android source compile SDK, and I get the SDK.zip，but can't find the tools folder.

My command in linux：

```
$. build/envsetup.sh

$lunch(sdk-eng)

$make sdk -j4
```

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Isn't it the `tools` folder right next to `tests`?

Comment: oh,sorry,this picture is error,this tools folder is copy from official SDK；